# How to remove a decimal part from alphanumberic string in java

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

String example = "1982.2 is a sample string with 6 digits"

Is there a way to do this in regex with it returning the string without the decimal part of it

result -> "1982 is a sample string with 6 digits"

Comment: `example.replaceAll("\\.\\d+", "");`

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?